# Block Connections From Other Devices

Tags: php, html, node.js

I have a website and I just want mobile devices to enter the site.So my question is how can I block connections from other devices.

I'm able to use node.js html and php in my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [mobile detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) class in PHP and then use a code like this :

```
// if visitor is not using any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( !$detect->isMobile() ) {
    die("access denied")
}
```